# Append a number of columns to create a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large number of columns in an Excel sheet that I want to convert into one long column in such a way that each sits on top of another. I don't want to concatenate values or merge columns. I can simply copy and paste but I have a huge number of columns.

Can anyone suggest any Excel trick for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste into Word as Unformatted Text. Select all, Convert Text to Table (one column), copy and paste back into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a Row of Values into a Column of Values is through the `TRANSPOSE` feature.

1. Highlight the range of cells
2. Copy
3. Select the Destination Cell
4. Right Click --> Paste Special
5. Select the Transpose checkbox

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: thanks, it does solve the problem to some extent. but i can;t select each row separately as i have long columns with thousands of rows, can it not be done on multiple columns instead of multiple rows?

Comment: My apology. I misread the question (too early in the morning!). Are you open to a VBA solution instead of one requiring Excel Formulas? I think I can write out some VBA to resolve the problem (presuming that I read the requirements correctly this time!)